# Rails 3: undefined method `page' for #<Array:0xafd0660>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, kaminari

I can't get past this. I know I've read there isn't a page method for arrays but what do I do?

If I run Class.all in the console, it returns #, but if I run Class.all.page(1), I get the above error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: Model.all in Rails 3 returns an array of records causing this issue. Model.all in Rails 4+ returns an ActiveRecord::Relation which you can indeed chain kaminari scopes, page and per, to. [Rails Release notes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No Array doesn't have a page method.

Looks like you are using kaminari. Class.all returns an array, thus you cannot call page on it. Instead, use Class.page(1) directly.

For normal arrays, kaminari has a great helper method:

```
Kaminari.paginate_array([1, 2, 3]).page(2).per(1)
```

Answer (score 12):

Kaminari now has a method for paginating arrays, so you can do something like this in your controller:

```
myarray = Class.all
@results = Kaminari.paginate_array(myarray).page(params[:page])
```

Comment: I get an undefined method "paginate_array" for Kaminari:module how to solve this?

Comment: @Þaw Sounds like you were using an older version of Kaminari.

Answer (score 5):

When you get an undefined method page for Array, probably you are using **kaminari** gem and you are trying to paginate your Model inside a controller action.

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `page' for # Array
```

There you need to remind yourself of two things, that the collection you are willing to paginate could be an **Array** or an **ActiveRecordRelation** or of course something else.

To see the difference, lets say our model is Product and we are inside our **index** action on **products_controller.rb**. We can construct our **@products** with lets say one of the following:

```
@products = Product.all
```

**or**

```
@products = Product.where(title: 'title')
```

**or** something else... etc

Either ways we get your @products, **however the class is different.**

```
@products = Product.all
@products.class
=> Array
```

**and**

```
@products = Product.where(title: 'title')
@products.class
=> Product::ActiveRecordRelation
```

Therefore depending on the class of the collection we are willing to paginate Kaminari offers:

```
@products = Product.where(title: 'title').page(page).per(per)
@products = Kaminari.paginate_array(Product.all).page(page).per(per)
```

---

*To summarise it a bit, a good way to add pagination to your model:*

```
def index
  page = params[:page] || 1
  per  = params[:per]  || Product::PAGINATION_OPTIONS.first
  @products = Product.paginate_array(Product.all).page(page).per(per)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end

end
```

and inside the model you want to paginate(product.rb):

```
paginates_per 5
# Constants
PAGINATION_OPTIONS = [5, 10, 15, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by invoking Kaminari's hooks manually. Add this line to run in one of your first initializers:

```
Kaminari::Hooks.init
```

I posted more details in another answer:

[undefined method page for #<Array:0xc347540> kaminari "page" error. rails_admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688256/undefined-method-page-for-array0xc347540-kaminari-page-error-rails-admin/13799169#13799169)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Did bundle update then restarted the server. One of the two fixed it.