# undefined method page for #<Array:0xc347540> kaminari "page" error. rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, kaminari, rails-admin

i am using rails_admin. when i go to certain resource. by typin url

```
localhost:3000/admin/rule
```

than it give me this error. code is:

```
scope = Rule.all
scope.page(1).per(2)
```

. above code is writtten in rails_admin gem.in a file named mongoid.rb placed in adaptors folder. complete log is:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #<Array:0xcea7408>):
mongoid (2.4.8) lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:385:in  `method_missing'
/home/usman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@system/bundler/gems/kaminari-809105ad782a/lib/kaminari/models/mongoid_extension.rb:11:in `page'
/home/usman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@system/bundler/gems/rails_admin-069819944cc9/lib/rails_admin/adapters/mongoid.rb:37:in `all'
/home/usman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@system/bundler/gems/rails_admin-069819944cc9/app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb:127:in `get_collection'
/home/usman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@system/bundler/gems/rails_admin-069819944cc9/app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb:39:in `list_entries'
/home/usman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@system/bundler/gems/rails_admin-069819944cc9/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/index.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Index>'
```

what should i do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4):

You can not call **Kaminari** methods on `Array`, because `Rule.all` will return `Array`.

So you have to do something like this: `Rule.page(1).per(2)`

Here is documentation and examples of **Kaminari** usage:

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Answer (score 4):

I've been running into this issue off and on for a while now using Mongoid. Sometimes refreshing the page in RailsAdmin would fix it.

I figured out that the problem is Kaminari's hooks are not initialized in my environment, so the models that rely on Kaminari's extension methods don't have them available.

I simply took the following line from [Kaminari's railtie](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/railtie.rb) and put it at the top of my [rails_admin initializer](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/generators/rails_admin/templates/initializer.erb):

```
Kaminari::Hooks.init
```

Now things seem to be working for me. However, I don't know why the ActiveSupport callback is not running that code.

Comment: fixed the same issue with mongo and rails_admin - 2 years passed and issue is still there

Comment: I get the same error for my array, except it's for `current_page` rather than `page`. Will this method still work at all? Also I'm not using Rails_admin

Comment: fixed for me using a required mongoid model inside a engine.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(Rule.all).page(params[:page])
```

Comment: That is the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Kader's solution is great! The only thing is I found I have to add .per to make it work.

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(Rule.all).page(params[:page]).per(PER_PAGE_RECORDS)
```