# Kaminari and Mongoid 'undefined method page' when model defined in separate gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, kaminari

I have a simple logging application consisting of ruby scripts and a "read-only" Rails application that reads from the MongoDB documents.  To keep the models consistent they both use a common gem where the Mongoid documents have been defined.

The problem I'm having is that Mongoid documents that are defined in the gem are not getting the Kaminari decoration.  In other words (simplified as much as possible).

```
# User is a Mongoid document defined in the Rails app (i.e. standard behavior)
require 'kaminari'
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    User.page(params[:pg]) # works great
  end
end
```

but

```
# SharedLogging::LogEntry is a Mongoid document defined in a separate gem
require 'kaminari'
class LogEntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    SharedLogging::LogEntry.page(params[:pg]) # undefined method 'page' for ...
  end
end
```

I think the solution is to do something in /config/initializers/kaminari_config.rb to force the pagination to be applied to the shared models but I haven't been able to stumble across the correct solution.

Alternately, I've also tried adding Kaminari as a dependency in the shared gem, but no luck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be resolved with the same solution described here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_mongoid/issues/10

In my kaminari_config.rb I've added the following lines:

```
SharedLogging::LogEntry.send(:include, Kaminari::MongoidExtensions::Document)
SharedLogging::LogEntry.send(:include, Kaminari::MongoidExtensions::Criteria)
```

The first line is required if I do `SharedLogging::LogEntry.page(params[:pg])` the second if I apply a scope first (e.g. `SharedLogging::LogEntry.by_date(params[:dt]).page(params[:pg])` ).

The biggest problem is that I need both lines for each model in my gem; and there are a lot of models.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manually extending, use Kaminari's hooks initializer. There are details in another answer I posted:

[undefined method page for #<Array:0xc347540> kaminari "page" error. rails_admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688256/undefined-method-page-for-array0xc347540-kaminari-page-error-rails-admin/13799169#13799169)

Comment: I just tried this but no luck. One problem might be the version. We're still on Kaminary 0.13 so the line would be ````Kaminari::Hooks.init!```` (with the bang) and perhaps there's other issues that prevent it from working. The other problem is probably the order the model gets included. I'm going to work with the initializers and see if I can get the init call to come in after the model is included.

Comment: There's definitely something wonky with the order classes are loaded. I was mainly getting the error on Heroku, and after a couple restarts the error eventually didn't come back (so far at least).